# Using server data store with Python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox, geoprocessing-service

ArcGIS Server lets you set server side data stores:

[image]

This is nice. I can use one connection on my local machine and another on my server. (Right? Please tell me I'm right.) But for the life of me, I can't find a way to actually set the data store on my geoprocessing service. My service is defined using a Python toolbox. It looks something like this:

```
import mygptool

class MyGPTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "MyGPTool"
        self.description = "Does my stuff!"

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        return [arcpy.Parameter(displayName="State (Abbreviation)"
                               ,name="state_abbreviation"
                               ,datatype="GPString"
                               ,parameterType="Required"
                               ,direction="Input"
                               )]

    # Boilerplate isLicensed, updateParameters, updateMessages methods

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        state_abbreviation = parameters[0].valueAsText
        mygptool.run_my_tool(state_abbreviation)
        return
```

I have a feeling I need to add something to this definition, but I'm having an awful lot of trouble figuring out *what* I need to add to give my service a connection to work with. (At the moment, I'm generating a temp connection file based on connection parameters in a config file, but that is something I'm looking to change as it doesn't make moving across environments very easy.)

A workspace parameter doesn't seem to help:

```
arcpy.Parameter(displayName="My Database"
               ,name="smart_db"
               ,datatype="DEWorkspace"
               ,parameterType="Required"
               ,direction="Input"
               )
```

This results in a constant parameter on my service, defeating the purpose of being able to specify the connection.

Also, I really do need a connection, not a table or feature class or what have you. The service creates multiple query layers using this connection; we're trying to avoid an MXD as this makes deployment much more difficult and tedious.

How can I make use of server configured data stores with a Python toolbox?

Answer (score 2):

The guts of the tool (python toolbox) have really nothing to do with the datastore.
The datastore is a look up table for ArcGIS Server that when publishing, makes decisions if the data needs to be copied or not.

So, if your tool takes a featureclass, when you publish, ArcGIS Server checks this lookup (datastore), and sees if the data is referenced or not. If it is, the data isn't copied. If the data is not matched in the datastore, then the data will be copied over to the server at publish time.

There is nothing you put in the tool in regards to datastore itself. After the tool is made, its just a matter of the data the tool requires to run.

However, I have a feeling this doesn't answer the problem you're having. Its not clear what is "wrong" thats happening.

Comment: "I can use one connection on my local machine and another on my server. (Right? Please tell me I'm right.)" Actually, I need to use different connections in different environments, and I don't want the people deploying to prod to have to recreate the service definition. The whole point is I need a variable connection. I guess I should revamp the question.

Comment: I opted to post a new question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102358/specify-geoprocessing-service-connection-at-publish. I may delete this one at some point.